# Best way to determine how many dynamic array(VLA) are used in source code

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, dynamic-arrays

I am currently working on porting a software to windows. I must use MSVC but this compiler doesn't support dynamic array (VLA). I could convert them to vector but the project is huge and maybe it's not a realistic way to solve this issue.
In order to decide, I need to know if there is a small or a huge amount of VLA, but I have no idea about how I could do that, do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: I mean if the compiler doesn't support them, don't you get an error for each use? You can count the errors then.

Comment: ...and it will tell you where they are.

Comment: Well, this is MS-Windows. On Linux one can simply run `make`, redirect stderr to a file then grep it to get the exact count. But here you have these pretty dialogs, windows, and buttons which make this simple task not that straightforward...

Comment: @SamVarshavchik you can do similar. You do not have to run it with pretty dialog boxes. In fact, I only compile MSVC from command line. I even use make files, they were not invented by Linus.

Comment: If counting the compiler errors under Windows is for whatever reason not practical, you might be able to recompile on the original platform, using a compiler flag like `-std=c89`, and count the relevant errors there.

Comment: All compilers rejects VLA with appropriate flags: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/r77s98jW9).

Comment: @Quimby well this is just one error among hundreds that I have, I guess some errors probably covers many of these issues

Comment: @helpMeToKeepMyJob If you can get the error list into a file, you can use `grep -c` on that file.  (Well, if you have `grep`, that is.)

Comment: @helpMeToKeepMyJob That is unfortunate but dumping all of them and filtering for VLAs is not a bad idea as other have suggested. Sure there might be X errors because VLAs failed but e.g. the first one should be searchable.

Comment: You can get rid of many inappropriate MS warnings by placing the following 3 lines `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` and `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE` and `#define _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE`, before the first `#include` directive in each file. Or perhaps the IDE has a way to do that globally (I don't use it).

Comment: Another thing you can do is to implement Linux non-standard functions yourself, instead of attending to every occurrence.

Comment: Ok thanks everyone for you quick answers I really appreciate it ! 
Maybe I say something stupid but is it possible that some errors more importants prevent this particular issue to trigger on the errorlist ?

Comment: @SteveSummit that was in reply to "*this is just one error among hundreds*"

Comment: @helpMeToKeepMyJob Are you saying you have reason to believe you have more VLA's than are reflected in your error output?

Comment: If so, then you might be able to relatively quickly fix just the high-priority, fatal errors, that are halting compilation.  Good compilers attempt to keep working even after most errors.  Some compilers stop after N errors, but should have a flag to adjust the limit if (as here) you really do want *all* of them.

Comment: If MSVC is treating "Can't find header file" as a fatal error, you could quickly create empty `.h` files for all the ones it's complaining about.

Comment: @SteveSummit Yes I'm afraid of that, idk how the error handler works but a fix issue at compil time can lead to another, that's why I wanted to looking for another way to evaluate my issue

Comment: @helpMeToKeepMyJob This is the kind of thing that a compiler really is the best tool for.  If the count is important to you, it's worth spending a small amount of time fixing enough of the other errors so that you can get a decent count out of the compiler for the one you want.  Depending on circumstances, it *might* be possible to construct an `egrep` pattern to count VLA declarations, but it'd be a fair amount of work, and would probably generate lots of false positives and negatives.

Comment: @SteveSummit Thanks for your replies, I think my case is really not that bad !

Comment: You could fairly easily write a `clang-tidy` check that finds VLAs (if one doesn't actually exist already).

Comment: By the way, if your version of MSVC supports `alloca`, that's another likely candidate for relatively easily replacing your VLA's with.

Comment: @SteveSummit Thank but vectors seem to be a better candidate to my eyes, sadly alloca seems more or less deprecated and got some security issues

Comment: @helpMeToKeepMyJob *I could convert them to vector but the project is huge* -- So I guess the original code didn't consider that VLA's may blow out the stack memory if a large amount of are being declared in a local block, and/or the size being used is too large?  A small number of errors or a large number of errors, maybe you have no choice but to address all of them.  The default stack memory in MSVC is (I believe) 1, maybe 2, megabytes.  With g++ under Linux, I think it's 8 MB, so rampant usage of VLA's may not have shown an issue due to the larger stack size.

Answer (score -1):

Paraphrasing comments to an answer:

> Your compiler doesn't support VLAs, so you get an error for each use. This allows you to count and even locate all use of VLAs.

> You can compile your program with MSVC using the command line and even makefiles to better extract the error list.